# SQL Server 2005 query with multiple conditions, some indexed, some not

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have a table with 50 million rows. It is indexed on zip. A query

```
Select * 
from table 
where zip = '12345'
```

returns 20,000 rows in about 2 seconds

When I add an additional condition it jumps to 15 minutes...

```
Select * 
from table 
where zip = '12345' 
  and otherField = 'Y'
```

My expectation is SQL would use the index, identify the 20,000 rows and then scan all for that non indexed condition. Maybe a few seconds at max. Instead it seems to be scanning the whole database table.

I cannot add another index... There are 150+ columns we might test, most have Y/N values.

Is there a better way to write this type of query?

Could I have a setting wrong in the server config?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the indexes on the table? What's the table definition? Why are you doing `SELECT *` when it sounds like you have 150 columns on the table. Do you really need all 150 returned?

Comment: We don't need all. I've done queries selecting just 10 columns, same result.  When select * with test index field only, it is just a few seconds. The issue is with the additional where clause condition that is not indexed.

Comment: The table definition is 200 columns, mostly varchar, with indexes on state, zip, last+firstname.    There are around 150 YN or 1 char fields on each row.

Comment: Is your index just on Zip or are you using `INCLUDE` to include the columns returned? Sounds like SQL Server making a choice between a scan and a seek/lookup due to a poor index. Might be worth posing the execution plans for both a good and bad query. You also don't have to add another index, indexing on `(zip,otherField) INCLUDE(myotherfields)` would satisfy both queries.

Comment: Sorry you are more advanced than me on this. Not familiar with INCLUDE. The index is just on Zip. I don't want to index on (zip,other1) because there is other2, other3, ..., other150.    Other1 is used in this lookup, but not in other lookups.   one query may filter by UsesMacYN while another might test UsesPCYN

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'd recommend reading up about covering indexes here https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/

Comment: Thanks Mark I will. So to you it doesn't look like a query issue, more of an index issue?  I hoped the query would find the 20,000 records by zip and scan those. Is there a way to force that behavior?

Comment: It'll be an index or maybe a statistics issue. Without seeing an execution plan I'd just be guessing what the issue is. You can force behaviour using an index hint, http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/08/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint-part2/ however there is normally a reason SQL Server chooses to do what it does. Forcing behaviour can result in poor performance if the data changes in future, or if you dropped the index

Comment: I read the article you linked to.   "SQL Server 2005 provided a new feature for nonclustered indexes, the ability to include additional, non-key columns in the leaf level of the nonclustered indexes. These columns are technically not part of the index, however they are included in the leaf node of the index. SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 allow up to 1023 columns to be included in the leaf node."   My DB is 300GB.  If I do this and include all 150 cols, will this double the DB size placing all 150 values in each leaf?  Or is it just a ref back to the cols and data is stored in the table

Comment: Is the index on zip a clustered index?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to write this type of query?

No, the way you've written it is the "best" way.  Unless, of course, that way doesn't work.  The joy and frustration of using a declarative language is the optimiser.  It is your best friend when it works and worst enemy when it doesn't.

One way to kick the optimiser into doing the right thing is to re-write your query in a semantically identically way such as:

```
select <whatever>
from table as t
inner join
    (
    Select <primary key columns>
    from table as b
    where b.zip='12345'
    ) as z
    on t.PrimaryKey = z.PrimaryKey  -- repeat if multi-column key
    and t.otherField = 'Y';
```

Now the optimiser is starting from a different place and may, possibly end up with a different, better, answer. For simple single-table queries I fear it is unlikely to show much change, however.

I would only suggest you try this after you're absolutely sure you've done all you can with indexes.  Re-writing queries in non-obvious ways adds maintenance overhead to the application.  It may also prove counter-productive when you patch or upgrade SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try selecting into a temp table with the zip criteria only, and then select from the temp table with the additional criteria.

`SELECT * INTO #MyTemp FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable where zip='1234') data
SELECT * from #MyTemp where other = 'Y'
DROP Table #MyTemp`

Not sure if this will be faster, but since the zip-only query runs fast, then you're just running a second query on 20,000 records.  Whether this is OK or not may depend on how much data is in a row, how much memory the server has, how fast the disk is where tempdb is located, etc.  Easy to try, anyway.

Comment: I also like this temp table solution since you can dynamically create another index on "otherfield" since that can be any column from your base table.  This way you avoid maintaining a huge index but it will be at the expense of relying more on tempdb.  Choices, choices...